# windows phone data validation

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, validation

I'm using Data Validation to validate user input, as in the example on msdn ( 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx )
everything works, but if I have a form with a save button, and I want to check that there are no validation errors, before to save, how can I do?

I thought about something like this:

```
foreach (var item in this.stkPanel.Children)
{
    if (Validation.GetHasError(item)) {
         ...
    }
}
```

but I do not like this.
is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not going to rewrite this entire article.

The short answer is yes, there is a much cleaner way, and more consistent way of doing this.

They are called validation rules / Business logic.

Basically they kind of work like converters do. You create the CS file with your rule logic in it then you tie it to your XAML.

I assume you mean some logic like this.

[image]

Here is the article on how to accomplish this

[MSDN Business Logic / Validation Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164107.aspx)

This is a much cleaner example than the MSDN one that doesn't account for Sharepoint

[Data Validation in Windows Phone 8](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/data-validation-windows-phone)